# Renaming bot x and y facets for ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to relabel both the x and y facets for a ggplot2 graph.

I've found multiple ways of writing a function to re-label one facet, but not both.

```
head(nh2)  
        RatioIncomePoverty Ethnicity Education mean.bmi  
1                  0         1         1       26.18333  
2                  0         1         1       30.88000  
3                  0         1         2       32.03000  
4                  0         1         4       34.45000  
5                  0         2         1       26.33000  
6                  0         2         2       23.44000  

b2 <- qplot(RatioIncomePoverty, mean.bmi, data=nh2, facets=Education~Ethnicity)
b2 = b2 + labs(list(title="Average BMI and Ratio of Family Income to Poverty Threshold     among US Ethnic groups", x = "Ratio of Family Income to Poverty Threshold", y = "Average BMI"))
b2
```

Currently both Education and ethnicity have values 1-5 for each and I'd like to rename to them  to what they corresponded to in the survey.

```
Education:    
1 = "<9th"  
2 = "9th-11th"  
3 = "GED"  
4 = "Some/AA"  
5 = "Grad"  

Ethnicity:  
1 = "Mex/Amer"  
2 = "OtherHisp"  
3 = "White"  
4 = "Black"  
5 = "Other/Multi"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply create factors with those as levels?

```
eth <- c('Mex/Amer', 'OtherHisp', 'White', 'Black', 'Other/Multi')
edu <- c('<9th', '9th-11th', 'GED', 'Some/AA', 'Grad')

nh2 <- within(nh2, {ethFac <- factor(Ethnicity, labels = eth)
                    eduFac <- factor(Education, labels = edu)})

 b2 <- qplot(RatioIncomePoverty, mean.bmi, data=nh2, facets=eduFac~ethFac)
```

Comment: Hmm - well that created the factors but I still get
"Error in layout_base(data, rows, drop = drop) : 
  At least one layer must contain all variables used for facetting"

Comment: I'll mark it answered, I had a capitalization typo in the variables used in facet. Thanks!